# CSS Column-Count in combination with hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic page that shows 9 blocks in 2 columns depending on what a user chooses as options. Each option having a seperate block. Initially all blocks are hidden. Once a user chooses the option, the block will be made visible and is positioned automatically in the 2 columns.

Say a user chooses the last option and thus the last block in the column-count will be made visible.

Now, what i would expect is that this last block will be on the left side without any lost space or margins or whatsoever. The result i am getting is that the block shows up on the right side, which i don't want. I looks just wrong.

I have an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh1v65zj/1/).

Any thought on how to prevent this unwanted behaviour?

**Container block**:

```
.container {
-webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
       column-count: 2;

-webkit-column-gap: 116px;
  -moz-column-gap: 116px;
       column-gap: 116px;

-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
}
```

**Hidden block**:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: There are two issues.  Change your hidden class to `display: none`.  Setting the visibility to hidden makes the element invisible but even though the height is zero it still exists in the DOM so it takes up space.  Second, your before: and after: psuedo elements also take up space in the DOM, so the before counts as content in the first column pushing the div to the next column

Comment: Correct, i now got it working. It was indeed both the display: none and the before and after statements. Thanks, if you give it as answer i'll give you credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. Change your hidden class to display: none. Setting the visibility to hidden makes the element invisible but even though the height is zero it still exists in the DOM so it takes up space.

Second, your before: and after: psuedo elements also take up space in the DOM, so the before counts as content in the first column pushing the div to the next column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use overflow or display:none; visibility:hidden doesn't take away the element from the flow, it is only not drawn.

example : https://jsfiddle.net/Lh1v65zj/5/

```css
.container {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 116px;
  -moz-column-gap: 116px;
  column-gap: 116px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.containerSpan {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.col-100 {
  width: 100%
}

.col-100::before,
.col-100::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: ""
}

.containerSpan {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-100 container">
  <div class="hidden containerSpan">
    <p><b>1: </b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac finibus magna, nec euismod dolor. Donec ac urna et lacus pellentesque efficitur. Sed dignissim ante sit amet leo gravida varius ut euismod est. Nulla magna augue, pharetra
      a eleifend vitae, semper a dolor. Nam tempus lacus ac imperdiet suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultrices turpis vitae iaculis vestibulum. Nullam ullamcorper mattis lacus nec accumsan. Aliquam efficitur enim in odio facilisis cursus.
      Quisque eu placerat diam, eget consectetur ex.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden containerSpan">
    <p><b>2: </b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac finibus magna, nec euismod dolor. Donec ac urna et lacus pellentesque efficitur. Sed dignissim ante sit amet leo gravida varius ut euismod est. Nulla magna augue, pharetra
      a eleifend vitae, semper a dolor. Nam tempus lacus ac imperdiet suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultrices turpis vitae iaculis vestibulum. Nullam ullamcorper mattis lacus nec accumsan. Aliquam efficitur enim in odio facilisis cursus.
      Quisque eu placerat diam, eget consectetur ex.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden containerSpan">
    <p><b>3: </b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac finibus magna, nec euismod dolor. Donec ac urna et lacus pellentesque efficitur. Sed dignissim ante sit amet leo gravida varius ut euismod est. Nulla magna augue, pharetra
      a eleifend vitae, semper a dolor. Nam tempus lacus ac imperdiet suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultrices turpis vitae iaculis vestibulum. Nullam ullamcorper mattis lacus nec accumsan. Aliquam efficitur enim in odio facilisis cursus.
      Quisque eu placerat diam, eget consectetur ex.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden containerSpan">
    <p><b>4: </b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac finibus magna, nec euismod dolor. Donec ac urna et lacus pellentesque efficitur. Sed dignissim ante sit amet leo gravida varius ut euismod est. Nulla magna augue, pharetra
      a eleifend vitae, semper a dolor. Nam tempus lacus ac imperdiet suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultrices turpis vitae iaculis vestibulum. Nullam ullamcorper mattis lacus nec accumsan. Aliquam efficitur enim in odio facilisis cursus.
      Quisque eu placerat diam, eget consectetur ex.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden containerSpan">
    <p><b>5: </b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac finibus magna, nec euismod dolor. Donec ac urna et lacus pellentesque efficitur. Sed dignissim ante sit amet leo gravida varius ut euismod est. Nulla magna augue, pharetra
      a eleifend vitae, semper a dolor. Nam tempus lacus ac imperdiet suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultrices turpis vitae iaculis vestibulum. Nullam ullamcorper mattis lacus nec accumsan. Aliquam efficitur enim in odio facilisis cursus.
      Quisque eu placerat diam, eget consectetur ex.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden containerSpan">
    <p><b>6: </b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac finibus magna, nec euismod dolor. Donec ac urna et lacus pellentesque efficitur. Sed dignissim ante sit amet leo gravida varius ut euismod est. Nulla magna augue, pharetra
      a eleifend vitae, semper a dolor. Nam tempus lacus ac imperdiet suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultrices turpis vitae iaculis vestibulum. Nullam ullamcorper mattis lacus nec accumsan. Aliquam efficitur enim in odio facilisis cursus.
      Quisque eu placerat diam, eget consectetur ex.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden containerSpan">
    <p><b>7: </b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac finibus magna, nec euismod dolor. Donec ac urna et lacus pellentesque efficitur. Sed dignissim ante sit amet leo gravida varius ut euismod est. Nulla magna augue, pharetra
      a eleifend vitae, semper a dolor. Nam tempus lacus ac imperdiet suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultrices turpis vitae iaculis vestibulum. Nullam ullamcorper mattis lacus nec accumsan. Aliquam efficitur enim in odio facilisis cursus.
      Quisque eu placerat diam, eget consectetur ex.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden containerSpan">
    <p><b>8: </b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac finibus magna, nec euismod dolor. Donec ac urna et lacus pellentesque efficitur. Sed dignissim ante sit amet leo gravida varius ut euismod est. Nulla magna augue, pharetra
      a eleifend vitae, semper a dolor. Nam tempus lacus ac imperdiet suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultrices turpis vitae iaculis vestibulum. Nullam ullamcorper mattis lacus nec accumsan. Aliquam efficitur enim in odio facilisis cursus.
      Quisque eu placerat diam, eget consectetur ex.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="containerSpan">
    <p><b>9: </b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac finibus magna, nec euismod dolor. Donec ac urna et lacus pellentesque efficitur. Sed dignissim ante sit amet leo gravida varius ut euismod est. Nulla magna augue, pharetra
      a eleifend vitae, semper a dolor. Nam tempus lacus ac imperdiet suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ultrices turpis vitae iaculis vestibulum. Nullam ullamcorper mattis lacus nec accumsan. Aliquam efficitur enim in odio facilisis cursus.
      Quisque eu placerat diam, eget consectetur ex.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also correct, but a bit less accurate compared to @sn3ll therefore the credits will go his way. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: @Matti.b to give credits, you should upvotes answers and accept the one you choose. Mainly the point was that visibility:hidden; doesn't remove the element from the dom/space in the document flow. height:0 needs overflow:hidden to be efficient and hide elements. display:none; removes elements from the DOM , but position:fixed or absolute + coordonates can do the job too keeping content accessible. Many ways and reasons why/how to do what you looked for. About styling display:none is plenty efficient, about accessibility  other ways can have their purpose too ;) .